# How to grab text variable with dynamic ID in Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm currently trying to grab bits of text data throughout a webpage. I initially grab all the webpages and slowly sift through the webpages grabbing the data I need off of each page. I'm having trouble for example grabbing items such as square footage or neighborhood because of the dynamic ID's. Many of the examples I have seen through XPath or CSS selector involve searching for the text, but that changes on each page that I am trying to scrape. Is there a way to capture the sq footage or neighborhood?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

from selenium import webdriver as wd
from selenium.common.exceptions import StaleElementReferenceException
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = wd.Firefox()

quote_page = "https://www.zillow.com/homes/for_sale/Minneapolis-MN/condo_type/5983_rid/0-175000_price/0-685_mp" \
             "/globalrelevanceex_sort/45.075097,-93.09248,44.866211,-93.430309_rect/11_zm/"

# print (soup.prettify())

driver.get(quote_page)
html = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
webURL = []

while True:
    try:
        element = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "element_id")))
    except TimeoutException:
        print("Timeout Exception")

    elems = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@href]")

    for elem in elems:
        try:
            if 'homedetails' in elem.get_attribute("href"):
                print(elem.get_attribute("href"))
                webURL.append(elem.get_attribute("href"))
        except StaleElementReferenceException:
            print("test")
    try:
        driver.find_element_by_link_text('NEXT').click()
        print('Going to next page')
    except NoSuchElementException:
        break

for item in webURL:
    print(item)

newPage = webURL[0]

driver.get(newPage)

price = driver.find_element_by_class_name("price").text

print(price)
```

Code currently is able to grab links and then open webpages. I have been able to grab data that has a unique name element.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're trying to locate an element (or the contents of an element) based on the ID of the content using a CSS selector, which is variable.

If that's the case, I believe that you would need to search the page for elements that match a certain pattern. You could accomplish this in a couple of different ways.

The simplest way might be to have a list of all the real-estate websites' different patterns of listing data that you would like to match (i.e. in the link of your post, the id element of the anchors all start with the same 4 id characters ("yui_[...]"), and the same href pattern ("/homedetails/[...]").

You can use this information along with some helpful XPath functions or CSS selectors to accomplish your goal:

- [`contains()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/contains) and [`starts-with()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/starts-with) XPath functions:

  ```
  //div[contains(., "Desired text")]
  //div[starts-with(., "Desired text")]
  ```
- [`preceding`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes/preceding), [`preceding-sibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes/preceding-sibling), [`following`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes/following) and [`following-sibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes/following-sibling) axis that might help you if you know the relative position of an newly generated block of elements you need to locate

---

There are also *CSS selectors* for partial match on element attributes:

```
a[href*=desiredSubstring]  # contains
a[href^=desiredSubstring]  # starts-with
a[href$=desiredSubstring]  # ends-with
```

---

And you can always find more elements than needed and filter them out later in Python, example:

```
import re

pattern = re.compile(r"^This \w+ text.$")

elements = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("div.some_class")
for element in elements:
    match = pattern.match(element.text)
    if match:
        print(element.text)
```

Good Luck!